# PHP Troubleshooting, exposing Classes being used, Globals, Session

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to find a tool, or platform that will allow me to program for effectively. Especially when it comes to using platforms like WordPress.

I would like to be able to see what classes are being loaded, variables have been created, methods executed, etc.

It's especially difficult when using a library for the first time and getting a grip on how to expand on that library with very little time to memorize it all.

The only IDE that I can really think of that comes close is ZEND Studio... but of course, that requires ZEND Server, and I prefer to use the lighter MAMP, or even built in stack on OS X.

Comment: Use the [xdebug profiler](http://xdebug.org/) to see what methods are being called. It will integrate with lots of text editors, or simply dump cachegrind files on the server to analyze with a debugger like valgrind or kcachegrind.

Comment: Zend Studio does not require Zend Server. But other good IDE's are eclipse with PDT, Netbeans, and Apanta.

Comment: @Pitchinnate in order to use something like Xdebug with Zend Studio, I've read all over the place that Zend Server is required... but maybe they're just pluggin their own platform. And Eclipse is terrible on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use step through debugging using Xdebug with IDEs like [Netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug) and Eclipse. Thats a good way of seeing whats going in libraries, plus the ides have good autocompletion.

Comment: I primarily use Coda 2... and so far I have not found any way to use it to debug PHP code.

Comment: I have never used that editor, doesnt look like it supports xdebug. May be worth trying one of the ones suggested if you want debugging support. I use it in netbeans constantly, makes life much easier

Comment: Netbeans wasn't so good on the Mac either. I swear the developers of these IDEs do it on purpose. Are you an OS X user or Windows?

Comment: I use netbeans on linux, never had any issues